# Send an Android Intent object through a socket?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was wondering whether an `Intent` Object can be sent through an `ObjectOutputStream` ? 
For example lets say we have a client(Y) server(X) both of which are Android based applications and Y created an intent but instead of running it, Y wants to send it to X through a `socket` where by X would start that intent, be it an `Intent` or `IntentService`.

Now i know i could do the same thing by sending the Action String of the Intent to X and create the Intent at X and start it provided that both X and Y have whatever that intent is starting, but i am wondering about sending the whole object Intent. Is it a serialized object and would it be possible to send it ? If yes, what would a security drawback of this theory?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean X and Y are located on different devices?

Comment: Yes of course, X and Y could be on different devices. X and Y could be both a client and/or server.

Comment: so it is unlikely that both devices will have the same set of apps/intents installed,  in that case what's the purpose of it?

Comment: Not to mention the security issues of some `ServerSocket` accepting arbitrary `Intent` structures as input and invoking them.

Comment: @pskink lets suppose that both apps X and Y have the same intents

Comment: @CommonsWare what if the service running the server socket is able to filter intents and dropping the not needed ones.

Comment: So they are your devices and if they both trust each other and are using secure communicatuon channel, what problem do you see?

Comment: @pskink whether an already created Intent object could be passed through a socket

Comment: Sir if you don't understand my question please say so and i will reexplain it all

Comment: Ok, use toUri/parseUri methods